# How to make a PUT request from ASP.NET core mvc to Web API in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to save the changes I make in my model through API call in my database. I have checked my API is working fine when I am running it individually on Web. But its giving me an error `StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'`. I am trying to send and object and trying to see whether the request made was completed or not. When I am trying to debug it, it is not sending hit on my API controller.

Here is my model class:

```
 public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
    }
```

PUT Method in API:

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("api/[controller]/{customer}")]
        public IActionResult EditCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            var cust = _customerData.EditCustomer(customer);
            if (cust == string.Empty)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

The method I am using in project to call API:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
                );
                var sum = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Customer/", customer);
                if (sum.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    
                    return RedirectToActionPermanent(actionName: "SingIn");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["msg"] = "There is an error";
                    return View();
                }
```

where baseaddress= {https://localhost:44398/}

---

EditCustomer Method

```
public string EditCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            try
            {
                var pro = _customerContext.Customer.Where(e => e.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
                pro.Age = customer.Age;
                pro.Phone = customer.Phone;
                pro.Name = customer.Name;
                _customerContext.Entry(pro).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _customerContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Psychonaut007, I suggest you can share your EditCustomer corresponding controller . Also please check your `customer` if it has correct value.

Comment: Hello @Rena I have shared the mentioned method but the problem is I am not receiving a hit in controller at the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix your action route by removing {Customer}, since you send customer in request body, not as a route value

```
 [Route("~/api/Customer")]
```

and request

```
  var sum = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("/api/Customer", customer);
```

or  better fix the acttion route name to meaningfull

```
  [Route("~/api/EditCustomer")]
```

and

```
var sum = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("/api/EditCustomer", customer);
```

AsJsonAsync sometimes causes problems

try this code

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customer);
//or if you are using Newtonsoft
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);

var contentData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PutAsync("/api/Customer", contentData);
              
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("SingIn");
else
{
 TempData["msg"] = "There is an error";
 return View();
}
```

but IMHO I would prefer to use

```
client.PostAsync("/api/EditCustomer", contentData);
```

instead of Put.

and added [FromBody] to action

```
 [HttpPost("~/api/EditCustomer")]
 public IActionResult EditCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Serge! I have applied above changes and got this error ```StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request```

Comment: I think it is your action problem. Use debugger inside of the API action and check if customer is not empty

Answer (score 0):

I am no pro in web APIs but I suspect it could be due to the fact that the API expects `customer` to be in request URL.

Try and change the API route to `[Route("api/[controller]")]`

This could've been a comment but I don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: Thanks this is working but i am looking for a solution where i can pass whole object just to make it more feasible in dealing with large number of variables.